# Concat fixed number of Optionals to Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have 3 Optionals:

```
Optional<T> optA = getOptA();
Optional<T> optB = getOptB();
Optional<T> optC = getOptC();
```

Is there a better way to concat them to a `Stream<T>` than:

```
Stream.concat(Stream.concat(optA.stream(), optB.stream()), optC.stream());
```

If the number of optionals grows, this gets unwieldy very soon:

```
Stream.concat(Stream.concat(optA.stream(), optB.stream()), Stream.concat(optC.stream(), optD.stream());
```

Comment: Is there a reason your optionals must be in separate variables instead of an array or list?

Comment: Sadly, there is. I would love to refactor the code responsible for that but I do not have the time to do so as it is a complicated architectural decision.

Comment: There are multiple approaches to represent a list of `Optional` into a `Stream`. Multiple answers can be referred to in the duplicate links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using `Stream::of` and concat in using reduce:

```
Stream.of(optA.stream(), optB.stream(), optC.stream(), optD.stream())
        .reduce(Stream::concat)
        .orElseGet(Stream::empty);
```

Or you can use a map, and your code should be:

```
Stream.of(optA, optB, optC, optD)
        .map(Optional::stream)
        .reduce(Stream::concat)
        .orElseGet(Stream::empty);
```

Which lead you to combine map and reduce using only `flatMap` as mentioned in comments:

```
Stream.of(optA, optB, optC)
        .flatMap(Optional::stream);
```

Comment: Based on your answer, `Stream.of(optA, optB, optC).flatMap(Optional::stream)`does also work